# How to make the ^ button stop raising things

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

I don't know if this is an Ubuntu problem but it doesn't do this when I boot into windows with the same computer. What happens is that when I press the <kbd>^</kbd> key, the next character is raised half way above the line (superscript formatted), like it would appear when writing something to the power of something. For example, if I type <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, I get y<sup>x</sup>.

I almost never want it to behave this way; I mostly write in latex where I would much rather the <kbd>^</kbd> key just print the `^` character.

Is there any way to disable this somewhere in the settings? I've searched the web but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I have never had that happen to me on Ubuntu. What version/flavour/desktop environment are you using?

Comment: Where do you see this behavior? What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: Swedish keyboard layout , Normal ubuntu 16.04